# Invoke-Sqlcmd unavailable from the ISE, but works in conventional Powershell host

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm having some trouble with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`

From the normal powershell console, it's fine. But I'm unable to use it from the ISE.

I can confim the addin is loaded

```
>Get-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Name        : SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
> add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin : Cannot add ... SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 ... it is already added.
```

when I try to use it

```
> Invoke-Sqlcmd
The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function ...
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know. I get a different error because I have ISE set to run with 4.0

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add the provider snapin:

`Add-PsSnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100`

Both are required for full functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the behavior you are seeing.  On 64-bit Windows, the SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 snapin appears to be 64-bit only.  Any chance you are trying to use it from a 32-bit ISE?  Check the title bar. If it say "Windows PowerShell 2.0 (x86)" then you're running the 32-bit ISE?

Comment: Test on both x86 and 64bit. Same problem. Perhaps it's just an issue w/ my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In one script that required `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100` i used this workaround:

```
$Name = SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
$Snapin = Get-PSSnapin -Name $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($Snapin -ne $null) {
    Remove-PSSnapin $Name 
}
Add-PSSnapin $Name
```